# How do I use a RouterChain with multiple chains that have different inputs?

Tags: langchain

This is my sample code:

```py
import langchain
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) # read local .env file

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.router import MultiPromptChain
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate


llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.9, model="gpt-3.5-turbo")

refuse_template = """Politely refuse to answer the question because it's not related to soccer or football"""
refuse_prompt = PromptTemplate(template=refuse_template, input_variables=[])
refuse_chain = LLMChain(prompt=refuse_prompt, llm=llm)

chat_template = [
    ("system", "you are an expert in football (what they call soccer in the US"),
    ("system", "you are English and therefore use english terminology when talking about football"),
    ("human", "answer this {input}")
]
chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(chat_template)
chat_chain = LLMChain(prompt=chat_prompt, llm=llm)

team_template = [
    ("system", "You are an expert in English football and can answer any question about any English team"),
    ("human", "answer this {input} about this {team}")
]
team_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(team_template)
team_chain = LLMChain(prompt=team_prompt, llm=llm)



destination_chains = {}
destination_chains["football"] = chat_chain
destination_chains["football"] = {"prompt":chat_prompt, "llm":llm}
destination_chains["refuse"] = refuse_chain
destination_chains["refuse"] = {"prompt": refuse_prompt, "llm": llm}
destination_chains["team"] = team_chain
destination_chains["team"] = {"prompt": team_prompt, "llm": llm}

descriptions = {
    "football": "Answers association football questions",
    "refuse": "Refuse to answer the question because it's not related to football / soccer",
    "team": "Answer a question specifically about an English football team. Extract the term 'team' as an output for this chain"
}

default_chain = ConversationChain(llm=llm, output_key="text")

from langchain.chains.router.llm_router import LLMRouterChain, RouterOutputParser

destinations = [f"{k}: {descriptions[k]}" for k in descriptions]
destinations_str = "\n".join(destinations)

print(destinations_str)

router_template = """
Given a raw text input to a language model select the model prompt best suited for the given input.
Extract relevant information and additional inputs for the next chain if necessary.  

<< FORMATTING >>
Return a markdown code snippet with a JSON object formatted to look like:
``json
{{
    "destination": string \ name of the prompt to use or "DEFAULT"
    "next_inputs": string \ String representation of a JSON containing the original input. Additional relevant keys extracted from the input should be included.
}}
``

REMEMBER: "destination" MUST be one of the candidate prompt names specified below OR it can be "DEFAULT" if the input is not well suited for any of the candidate prompts.
REMEMBER: "next_inputs" is a string. It is just the original input, and may contain "team" if a team is found in the text.

<< CANDIDATE PROMPTS >>
{destinations}

<< INPUT >>
{input}

"""

print(router_template)

router_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template=router_template,
    input_variables=[
        "destinations",
        "input"
    ],
    output_parser=RouterOutputParser(),
)

router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm, router_prompt)


chain = MultiPromptChain(
    router_chain=router_chain,
    destination_chains=destination_chains,
    default_chain=default_chain,
    verbose=True,
)

langchain.debug = True

question = "How many league titles have Manchester United won?"
output3 = chain.run({"input":question, "destinations": destinations_str})

question = "How many players are on a football team?"
output1 = chain.run({"input":question, "destinations":destinations_str})

question = "What do you think of Boris Johnson?"
output2 = chain.run({"input":question, "destinations": destinations_str})

print("---")
print("---")
print("---")
print("---")
print(output1)
print("---")
print(output2)
print("---")
print(output3)
```

My problem is that sometimes I need output from the router in a different format depending on the destination chain. Is there a way to handle this?

In my case for `question3` I get this error:

```
{
  "destination": "team",
  "next_inputs": {
    "input": "{\"text\": \"How many league titles have Manchester United won?\", \"team\": \"Manchester United\"}"
  }
}
[chain/error] [1:chain:MultiPromptChain] [2.82s] Chain run errored with error:
"ValueError(\"Missing some input keys: {'team'}\")"
```

Is there a more standard way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I have the same error. It seems like nobody has an answer :D

Comment: Also encountering this error. This Issue thread proposed some promising adaptor patterns, but sadly I couldn't get any to work. Might help give someone else some ideas though:  https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/6931

Answer (score 0):

As of now you can't use multiple inputs through RouterChain in Python, but it's possible in NodeJs. I tried there output parsers and created mine also but in python it doesn't work the way it worked in NodeJs.

You can do one thing, you can replace the strings and pass single input to the router chain, it will work for you. cheers :)

May be in future langchain will provide a solution for that as it's drastically changing.